# how to set property as val at customview written by xml

Tags: android, kotlin

In case of below, MyView's callback is not mutable property so I want to declare as val.
Not only that, Since it can not be initialized at init function, it is error prone.
How to set callback as val or... how to set callback in the init function?
Thanks

```
class MyView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context, attributeSet) {
    lateinit var callback: Callback
    init {
        //callback = 
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        my_view.callback = object : Callback {
        }
    }
}

<LinearLayout>
    <com.example.MyView
        android:id="@+id/my_view/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the reason you are using callback because you want to receive call back in Activity. if you set callback in init function, then how your Activity able to receive callback.

Comment: Yes What I want is receving callback from MyView to Activity.
As you said, "if I set callback in init function" <- this means I have to receive callback as Constructor's parameter.
But Inflating from xml, it's impossible i think. That's why I am ask

Comment: yes, it's impossible to set callback in xml layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set `callback` from another class, e.g. `Activity`, this property must be mutable:

```
class MyView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context, attributeSet) {
    var callback: Callback? = null
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        my_view.callback = object : Callback {

        }
    }
}
```

If you want `callback` to be immutable you should initialize it in `MyView` class:

```
class MyView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context, attributeSet) {
    val callback: Callback = object : Callback {

    }
}
```

But in this case you won't be able to update it from another class.